# Обновление timepickerа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно было сделать обычное бронирование времени в зависимости от выбранной даты, данные берутся по ajax запросу, все хорошо, но есть одно но, оно не обновляется после выбора даты во второй раз. Сколько не пробовал всяких методов - не получается, и .remove() и .detach() и .empty()

```
function showdate() {

var date = $("#datetimepicker2").val();
if (date == "") {
    alert("Сначала выберите дату");
}
else {
    var ajx;
    ajx = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/date_from_ajax/",
        data: {
            "data": date
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (dat) {
            var leng = dat['time_list'].length;
            if (leng == 0) {
                var a0 = "";
                var a1 = "";
                var a2 = "";
                var a3 = "";
                var a4 = "";
            }
            if (leng == 1) {
                var a0 = [(dat['time_list'][0]), ((Number((dat['time_list'][0])) + 1).toString())];
                var a1 = "";
                var a2 = "";
                var a3 = "";
                var a4 = "";
            }
            if (leng == 2) {
                var a0 = [(dat['time_list'][0]), ((Number((dat['time_list'][0])) + 1).toString())];
                var a1 = [(dat['time_list'][1]), ((Number((dat['time_list'][1])) + 1).toString())];
                var a2 = "";
                var a3 = "";
                var a4 = "";
            }

             foo.timepicker({
                  'disableTimeRanges': [
                    a0,
                    a1,
                    a2,
                    a3,
                    a4
                ],
                 'timeFormat': 'H:i',
                'minTime': '8',
                'maxTime': '16',
                'step': 120
             })
       }
    });
}
```

То есть каждый раз нужно удалять старый timepicker, подскажите как это правильно сделать! Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам стоит подписаться на событие change у timepicker
http://timepicker.co/options/ как в документации и устанавливать в инпут нужное вам значение.

```
$(document).ready({ 
    $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
       change: function(time) { 
        //инпут 
        var element = $(this); 
        //доступ к таймпикеру 
        var timepicker = element.timepicker();                 
        element.val(timepicker.format(time)); 
      } 
  }); 
})
```